# spark logistic regression for binary classification: apply new threshold for predicting 2 classes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, classification, logistic-regression

I am new to both Spark and Python. I used Spark to train a Logistic Regression model with just two classes (0 and 1). I trained it using my train data frame.

This is how my pipeline model was defined:

```
# Model definition:
lr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol = "lr_features", labelCol = "targetvar")
# Pipeline definition:
lr_pipeline = Pipeline(stages = indexStages + encodeStages +[lr_assembler, lr])
# Fit the logistic regression model:
lrModel = lr_pipeline.fit(train)
```

Then I ran predictions using my test dataframe:

```
lr_predictions = lrModel.transform(test)
```

Now, my lr_predictions has a column 'probability' that looks like a nested list to me. For example, its first cell contains:
[1,2,[],[0.88,0.11]]
I assume, it means: the probability for class 1 (which is = 0) is 0.88, the probability for class 2 (which is = 1) is 0.11.

By default (threshold = 0.5) this observation is predicted 
as 0. However, I found a value (bestThreshold) that maximizes the F-measure (in my case it's 0.21):

```
fMeasure = lr_summary.fMeasureByThreshold
bestThreshold = fMeasure.orderBy(fMeasure['F-Measure'].desc()).first().threshold
```

I would like to apply bestThreshold to the 'probability' column and get a new
column ('pred_new', for example) that contains the class assignments (0 or 1) based on bestThreshold as opposed to 0.5.

I cannot use the code below, because 'probability' column is too complex:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
lr_predictions = lr_predictions.withColumn("prob_best", \
              when(lr_predictions["probability"] >= bestThreshold, 1).otherwise(0)
```

I feel I need to need to map the 'probability' to a new column based on a new threshold. But I am not sure how to do it - given this complex (for me) structure of the 'probability' column.

Thank you so much for your advice!

Answer (score 4):

If `lrModel` is `LogisticRegressionModel`:

```
type(lrModel)
## pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel
```

You can use internal Java object to set threshold

```
lrModel._java_obj.setThreshold(bestThreshold)
```

and transform:

```
lrModel.transform(data)
```

You can do the same to modify `rawPredictionCol`, `predictionCol` and `probabilityCol`.

This should become part of the public API in the future (2.3):

```
lrModel.transform(data, {lrModel.threshold: bestThreshold})
```

You can also use UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, lit

@udf("integer")
def predict(v, threshold):
    return 0 if v[0] >= bestThreshold  else 1

lr_predictions.withColumn(
   "prob_best",
   predict(lr_predictions["probability"], lit(bestThreshold)))
```

**Edit**:

With `PipelineModel` you can try to access `LogisticRegressionModel` (as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47685234/8371915)) and do the same thing.

Comment: didn't know that (+1)...!

Comment: how do I set the threshold on a mllib logisticregression model? I get the following error when I tried AttributeError: 'LogisticRegressionModel' object has no attribute '_java_obj'

Comment: @Mike https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=threshold#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.setThreshold