# Getting a BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary from the output of a Pipeline model in Spark 2.2.0

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I had previous been working with a logistic regression model in Spark 2.2.0 and by calling the model's `evaluate()` method on some labelled test data I was able to get a `BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary` object which I then used for some downstream tasks.

Now I am working with a `PipelineModel` where the last stage is a logistic regression model.  The problem is that a `PipelineModel` does not have an `evaluate` method, it only has a `transform` method which outputs a dataframe containing the predictions and labels. Is there any way to obtain a `BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary` object from the output of a `PipelineModel`'s transform method or in any other way using a `PipelineModel`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out one way of doing this.  I basically manually transform all transformations up until the model.  I then extract the last model stage and call the evaluate method on the output of the last stage output.

```
val plModel = loadModel

// iterate through all stages except last to get transformed features
val transformedFeatures = (inputDf /: plModel.stages.dropRight(1)) {
  case (acc, stage) => stage.transform(acc)
}

// extract model from last stage
val lrModel =
  plModel
    .stages
    .last
    .asInstanceOf[LogisticRegressionModel]

lrModel
  .evaluate(transformedFeatures)
  .asInstanceOf[BinaryLogisticRegressionSummary]
```

Comment: Instead of manually transforming all preceding stages, why not define a shorter pipeline and use that for the transformations?

Comment: Yeah that's probably a better idea

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that the last stage of the PipelineModel is the LogisticRegressionModel you need evaluated, try using something like `lr = thePipelineModel.stages[-1]` to get a reference to (what you expect will be) the correct object, and evaluate that.

Comment: Also note this is answered elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47685234/spark-extracting-summary-for-a-ml-logistic-regression-model-from-a-pipeline-mod?rq=1

Comment: Hi @hwrd the link you posted is a slightly different use case.  It looks like the link's use case is to get the training summary which I know how to get.  My use case is at prediction time.  At prediction time I still need the stages of the pipeline before the logistic regression model for preprocessing the input so I'm not sure that extracting the model from the last stage and calling the evaluate method would work.